# How to display TextField at the bottom of the screen

Tags: qml, textfield, qtquick2, sailfish-os

I want to display a `TextField` at the bottom of the screen in QML for SailfishOS.

I attempted multiple tries but the `TextField` is always at the top of the screen.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Sailfish.Silica 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
     id: screen
     anchors.fill: parent
    Item {
        width: parent.width;
        anchors.bottom: screen.bottom
        TextField {
            width: parent.width;
            anchors.bottom: screen.bottom
            id: input
            placeholderText: "URL"
            inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText
            validator: RegExpValidator { regExp: /^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$/ }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Kaymaz**, in common, your question is not related to SailfishOS. And you was almost right, but made several errors in your code. You can use this code:

```
// Its desktop version, and everyone can run it. It will be easy 
// to insert correct includes for SailfishOS
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: appWindow

    // Explicitly set window size (just for testing on desktop)
    width: 200
    height: 400

    // Item that represents "main application rectangle"
    // it will contain all child items
    Item {
        id: root
        anchors.fill: parent

        TextField {
            id: input
            anchors {
                left: parent.left
                right: parent.right
                bottom: root.bottom
            }
            placeholderText: "URL"
            inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText
            validator: RegExpValidator { regExp: /^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$/ }
        }
    }
}
```

I do not recommend use **folibis**'s approach for several reasons:

- If you can use `anchor`s in QML -- use it.
- Avoid unnamed constants (like `30`).
- Such code becomes hard to read (I mean, if it is more than 20 lines).
- Imagine, that your `TextField`'s height change -- you got need to change `y: screen.height - 30`. So this kind of code becomes hard to maintain.
- Do not write code thinking "I can improve this later". Write good code.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel if you can just walk.  Or, in accordance with Occam's razor - the fewer assumptions that are made, the better. You insert additional `Item` so this construction is became totally non-semantic. As for my solution - you can change it to `y: screen.height - height` and so all you may need to change here is `height`.

Comment: I also updated my answer. If you say it's hard to read ... hmm, I just have nothing to argue.

Comment: @troyane It works as expected, thanks.
But I've a litlle bit more of lines and I cannot make it work... Can you have a look please?
http://pastebin.com/xKzFLEFu

Comment: @Kaymaz if you have new question -- it is better to open new question with detailed description

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```js
ApplicationWindow {
    id: screen
    width: 400
    height: 300

    TextField {
        width: screen.width
        y: screen.height - height
        placeholderText: "URL"
    }
}
```

Comment: I found it out at the same time...odd stuff! Hopefully, it should work with landscape.

One small thing:  I use ´anchors.fill: parent´ so it takes all the screen

Comment: It would also work with anchoring...it was the outer `Item` to generate the visual error...always prefer anchoring to absolute positioning.

Comment: I do not recommend use this approach. See answer below.